# markdown emph regex match

Tags: regex, swift, markdown

raw string:

`These * should * not \*be\* selected. This* neither! *should be. This *neither should\* be* *this should* and*This*`

expect:

`These * should * not *be* selected. This* neither! *should be. This *neither should* be* <em>this should</em> ～～and<em>This</em>～～`

old regex:

`"(^|[\\W_])(?:(?!\\1)|(?=^))(\\*|_)(?=\\S)((?:(?!\\2).)*?\\S)\\2(?!\\2)(?=[\\W_]|$)"`

the old one is not good enough to deal with that situation

could someone help? swift regex

Comment: Please take some time to review your formatted question and to write a proper question (hint: there should be a "?" somewhere)

Comment: Better option is a custom parsing code, or you may try to match any escape sequence as the first alternative and then match and capture this markdown. Something like [`"\\\\.|(\\B\\*\\b(?:(?!\\\\[*]).)*?\\b\\*\\B)"`](https://regex101.com/r/aI0jI4/4).

Comment: what about https://regex101.com/r/wG7iA1/1

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew you're right， thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful with a regex approach when parsing markdown with regex since your data can have escape sequences. That means, you cannot just use lookarounds to match something if  it is not preceded with backslash. What you can try to do with regex is to match escape sequences coming before the markdown into one group and the markdown parts into another.

```
"(?u)(\\\\.)|(\\*\\b(?:(?!\\\\[*]).)*?\\b\\*)"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB5lT2/2). Inside the code, you need to handle these 2 groups differently as per your specifications.

*Pattern details*:

- `(?u)` - make the word boundaries Unicode-aware in the pattern
- `(\\\\.)` - Group 1 - an escape sequence
- `|` - or
- `(\\*\\b(?:(?!\\\\[*]).)*?\\b\\*)` - Group 2 matching

  - `\\*\\b` - a `*` that is followed with a word char
  - `(?:(?!\\\\[*]).)*?` - any char that is not a starting char of a `\*` sequence, as few as possible
  - `\\b\\*` - a `*` that is preceded with a word char

**Better option is a custom parsing code**.

Comment: `*寫作*用語言`
`*Hello*` 
`123\. *asdf*`
this situation the first not work, 3rd will match `\.`

Comment: I am checking now, it looks like the `(?u)` works - `"(?u)(\\\\.)|(\\B\\*\\b(?:(?!\\\\[*]).)*?\\b\\*\\B)"`

Comment: Look here what it matches - http://iswift.org/playground?Damq5d. What do  you expect? Or a regex fiddle - https://regex101.com/r/dB5lT2/1

Comment: em, expect is `["*寫作*", " *Hello*", "*asdf*"]`

Comment: It seems the non-word boundaries are irrelevant for you - remove them - [`(?u)(\\.)|(\*\b(?:(?!\\\*).)*?\b\*)`](https://regex101.com/r/dB5lT2/2) (in code, double the backslashes).